# VBA get value having string containing listbox control name

Tags: ms-access, vba

Silly question but I got lost.
In a VBA function I've some text which contains a string representing a listbox control name (ctrlName is the variable containing the control name).
VarText should give back the value of the selected (row/column) from listbox (error occurred here).

```
Function getString_email(..)

Dim ctrlName As String
Dim getString_email  as String
Dim sBody as String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim frm As Form
...
...
sBody = RS("Body")
ctrlName = Mid(sBody, StartVar, EndVar - StartVar)
Set frm = Forms("frmCatalogue")    
    VarText = frm.Controls(ctrlName)
Set frm = Nothing
...
... 
getString_email = Replace(sBody, ctrlName, VarText)
...
```

error: Run-time error 2465. can't find the field referred to in your expression.

Any help will be great!

Comment: The message is pretty clear. There is no control on the form frm named the value of ctrlName.

Comment: ty Gustav for your answer, but the form named "frmCatalogue" has a control (listbox) named "lst_Artists" which is exactly the value of ctrlName variable. The msg error doesn't help, I think is not explaining correctly. Any other control in the form works correctly, the issue rises because is a listbox?

Comment: Hard to believe. Please show the output of `Debug.Print ctrlName` and For each c in frm.Controls: Debug.Print c.Name: Next c`(as text).

Comment: Immediate window results:

    ?getString_email("tbl_EmailStrigns",2,5)
    Control Name: [Lst_Affiliates].[column](3)
    Control Names List: Lst_Affiliates, TabClients  ...
@ComputerVersteher

Comment: Of course edit your question and make clear what is the output of crtlName and what is the controls-collection. crtlName is `[Lst_Affiliates].[column](3) ` ? That is not equal to `Lst_Affiliates`.

Comment: output of crtlName is: [Lst_Affiliates].[column](3) and what I need is not the value of Lst_Affiliates (listbox), instead I need the 3rd column value of the Lst_Affiliates control @ComputerVersteher

Comment: I fear asking why you are doing that  ;) What different kind of values do you need? Always the column of a listbox? You see your mistake? `Lst_Affiliates` is a ListBox-Control that has a property named `Column`. The Controls-Collection of the form just contains the ListBox, so you have to ask it for `Lst_Affiliates` not its properties.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - the column index is variable, it changes depending on needs. The result of this function will concatenate string only using tables and controls around the db. Yes, I need to ask the variable ctrlName (which contains in this case Lst_Affiliates) its value of row/column index contained in the same variable. Sorry if was't clear in first instance.

Comment: You still need to explain what you are doing. From where and why do you get a string that can contain various form elements as string. That is weird and there should be an easier solution to archive what you want, but you have to tell!! As example you can get you desired value with `VarText = CallByName (frm.Controls("Lst_Affiliates"), "Column",vbGet,3)` You can split your received [Lst_Affiliates].[column](3) and insert to the CallByName arguments, but with differnt kind of controls this  will get difficult.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - strings are contained in tables (the function needs table name as param.), sBody contains both text and "strings variables". Agree with you, looks wired, because i'm pretty sure there should be a very easy solution around (like CType function in VB). What I need to do? Concatenate text by replacing variables with other text from around tables and forms.
Your function make the trick if I hardcore Lst_Affiliates, Lst_Affiliates and 3, but [Lst_Affiliates].[column](3) is a variable so could be any other "simpler" control

Comment: I just rembered `Eval` but as far as I know it is not very reliable, just try. `VarText = Eval("Forms(""frmCatalogue"")!" & ctrlName)` this evaluates the wanted value from a string. Keep in mind that you have to escape double-Quotes by doubleing, in  Forms("FormName") then concat your `ctrlName` with the control and the rest. Good luck ;) If this doesn't work for you, you have to briefly explain what you want to archive and how you do it till now!